# how to send notification from Laravel website to react native app

Tags: laravel, react-native, push-notification

I have a shopping website, I want to send notification to admin when a user place orders.
website in Laravel and admin is react native mobile app.
How can I do this?
Please help..

Answer (score 0):

1. Use Socket.io for instant Notification
2. You can use FCM token and send notification on mobile